# How to wait 1 second to move another slider after click using swiperjs api?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am having difficulty to figure out how to wait or delay slider about 1 second before move to another slider. The below is JavaScript. I am not sharing the html code because its too lengthy and my question will look messy. I hope some of you have idea. I really appreciate your help.

Js code

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
 
    autoHeight: true, //enable auto height    
    mousewheelControl: false,
    touchRatio: 0,
    allowTouchMove: false,
    shortSwipes: false,
    speed:2000,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    },

});
```

Comment: What is a `Swiper`?

Answer (score 0):

> I am having difficulty to figure out how to wait or delay [...] about 1 second

If you wish to delay script execution, you need `setTimeout`.

---

**Anatomy of setTimeout:**

```
setTimeout( [CALLBACK FUNCTION], [TIME DELAY] );
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const myButton = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

const clickButton = () => {

  setTimeout(() => {
  
    let myParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    myParagraph.textContent = 'You clicked the button.';
    document.body.appendChild(myParagraph);

  }, 1000);

}

myButton.addEventListener('click', clickButton, false);
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
<p>A second after you click the button above, more text will appear...</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This way swiper is not working. I tried timeout as u mentioned and inside swiper object as well. but its not working. do u have any clue to work this out.Thanks

Comment: Inside the `setTimeout()` function you only need to include the function you wish to delay execution of.